Man and his mother try to transport their gold bars in a portable house
I watched this film when I was a boy, about 20 years ago. I believe it is an American movie. In my language, the title was translated as “Money Greedy Guys.” The story revolves around a man and his mother attempting to smuggle their gold, which is concealed within the bricks of a portable house.
One memorable scene features the protagonist chasing a $100 bill blowing in the wind. He finally catches it, only to discover that it’s stuck to dog feces.

Do you know the country of origin for the film?  That usually helps in identifying it.

You really need to flesh this question out. As it sits, it's ripe for closure because you really aren't giving much detail about the movie.

@JohnnyBones I thinks it is USA

@Paulster2 the name of film was translated into my language has the meaning "money greedy guys" :(

This is the 1993 comedy La soif de l'or, though you misremembered a few things (it's his grandmother, and the film's French). The title contains variations of 'greedy' in some countries. From IMDb:

Urbain and his grandmother are stingy. They buy gold with all their money, and hide it inside the bricks of a wall at their country house. Jackes, his chauffer, and his lover (who casualy is the Urbain's wife) don't know this fact and think they have the money hidden somewhere. When Urbain and his grandmother decide to transport the gold (with the house!) to Switzerland, in order to pay less tax, a crazy chase begins.

There's also a scene with the protagonist running after a large bill blowing in the wind and the bill lands in dog poo. Here's a clip from the movie with the house (and grandma) being carried by a helicopter:



